# hide error message on click

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I've got a simple login form with email and password I have this code to validate the email

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#login-submit').click(function() {

    $(".error").hide();
    var hasError = false;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    var emailaddressVal = $(".email").val();
    if(emailaddressVal == '') {
        $(".email").after('<span class="error">Please enter your email address.</span>');
        hasError = true;
    }

    else if(!emailReg.test(emailaddressVal)) {
        $(".email").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid email address.</span>');
        hasError = true;
    }

    if(hasError == true) { return false; }

    });
});
```

the span with the class of .error (as per the design I've got) hides the input element.

I want to hide the error message again when I click it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.error').click(function() {
    $(".error").remove();
});

});
```

but this does nothing. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

Currently, you are binding the `click` handler to any `.error` element that exists *on page load*. But your `.error` messages are added to the DOM dynamically *after page load*, so your `click` handler is not bound to them.

**Solution**

Instead of directly *binding* the event handler to the elements, you should *delegate* the event handler higher up the DOM to a parent element that exists on page load.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.error', function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

This will have the `click` handler apply to any `.error` element included in the DOM, both current and future. You can of course limit the scope of delegation, by attaching it for example to `$('#some-form')` instead of `$(document)`.

Comment: how do I go about correcting this? jQuery is not my real skillset. Any pointers into how to sort this? Links to a tutorial or similar? (thanks)

Comment: Thanks @Boaz, this works perfectly. Thank you updating the answer to include an explanation. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Bootstrap alert messages.  They're really simple to use, and work within your page really simply, as they come with their own close buttons.  You can treat them as you would treat any other DOM element, but without the hassle.  All you have to do is install their library and use their classes/javascript in order to get what you want.  It takes a bit of getting used to, but it's an incredibly powerful addition.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts

Comment: thanks Ian, unfortunately I'm co-coding with someone else who's already created most of the HTML/CSS so this isn't an option. Thanks for the link though. Bookmarking and taking a look now